# Info Window Shadow very abnormal in IE8 when zoom is set as 125

Tags: google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8

The info window in google maps api V3 looks very abnormal and dark when zoom is set as 125.Is there any fix for this?

Comment: What version of the API are you using?  Have you have tried visualRefresh set to true?

Comment: Version 3.No, I haven't tried visualRefresh option

Comment: Which [version 3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) (3.11, 3.12, 3.13). For the new look (visualRefresh: true) "All shadows have been removed in the visual refresh. Any shadows specified programmatically will be ignored."

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure of the version.I use the foll url:http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

Comment: That is currently using 3/13/8.  Visual refresh becomes default in August ([per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#VisualRefresh), but if you set `google.maps.visualRefresh = true;` that should remove all shadows (they will be going away shortly anyway).

Comment: Ok, but will there be any other side effects in adding `google.maps.visualRefresh = true`

Comment: Read the documentation on [visualRefresh](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#VisualRefresh), it is coming in a few months whether you turn it on or not.  You can use the "frozen" version and perhaps avoid it for 9 months to a year, but after that you won't have any choice.

Comment: Sorry I had one more doubt.I understand that 3.12 is more stable.So If I use 3.12 will the above issue be solved?

Comment: Can't answer that with the information provided (none), sounds like a css problem to me, but I can't see it...

Comment: But I get those dark shadows even for the simplest map.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You haven't posted anything, I changed the zoom to 125 on IE, didn't see anything weird, is it specific to your computer?  Your website?

Comment: Even `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays`  is giving me the same issue.Its IE 8 and windows 7.I really don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: It is [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays)

Comment: [That page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays) looks OK to me in IE9, I see what you mean in IE8.  Probably should [open an issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/) as IE8 is [a supported browser](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport).

Comment: This was logged as an issue http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2797

Comment: And marked as WontFix (which doesn't surprise me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in IE8.  [The issue on the Google Maps API v3](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2797) is marked as "WontFix".